# GPIO pins available for switches

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio, switches

Among all the 40 GPIO pins, how many of them are available to connect a switch for on-off information?

I counted more than 24 `GPIO_*` connections here, but **are they all available via Python?**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
if GPIO.input(17):
    ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The 40 pin expansion header connects to 28 GPIO.  They are Broadcom GPIO 0 through 27.

You are recommended not to use GPIO 0/1 as they are intended to be used by HATs.

Any recent GPIO library will give access to all the GPIO connected to the expansion header.

Comment: Thanks. Can GPIO 2/3 be used for an open/closed switch? it seems that no, because of the pull-up resistor (?). Is there a way to use these 2 GPIO anyway?

Comment: You can use 2 and 3 for a button switch.  You could connect the other end to ground when closed.  The downside is just the waste of 3V3 through 1k8, or 2mA when the switch is operated.